# Force empty div with background image to cover height of container div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I have a row with two columns. I would like the column containing the `.product-image` empty div with background image (on the right) to have the same height as the column containing the `.product-text` div with text (on the left). The background image should cover the entire area of the right column.

I've created a codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VemgQb

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid subpage-product">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 product-text">
      <div class="product-icon">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/5a/dc/89/5adc89f4a0752dfec5c2f9ba625bfac5.jpg">
      </div>
      <h2>Meow Meow Meow</h2>
      <p>Pelt around the house and up and down stairs chasing phantoms shove bum in owner's face like camera lens stare at ceiling.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 no-padding product-img" id="horse-racing-bg-img-01">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (LESS):

```
  #horse-racing-bg-img-01 {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/C9xULnI.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  .subpage-product .row {
    overflow: hidden;
    .product-text {
      padding: 70px 100px;
      text-align:center;
      background-color: #000;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .product-img {
      height: 100%;
    }
    .product-icon {
      height: 80px;
      width: 80px;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto 0;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 1px solid white;
      background-color: #fff;
      img {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        margin: 15px 15px 0 13px;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm 99% sure that you can't. Other solutions : div with fixed height, table display, javascript, flexbox 

My favorite is flexbox but javascript could be a fallback :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Ianis . Do you know which flexbox styling can be used to achieve this effect? I tried adding `display: flex` to the parent element (row) and `flex-direction: column` to the child div but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Alright - I think I got it. Thanks for the reference @Mi-Creativity.
Updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjQMbq